# What is the preferred way to limit data fetched for lists in JPA / Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to figure out the right way to load only some properties for a list view displaying hundreds of rows.

For example, imagine a Person entity, which has a lot of properties but I only want to get first and last name for my lists.

What is the best way of achieving this with Hibernate/JPA?

A) Should I arrange my entities so that they only hold a few properties and the rest are in separate entities (and tables) using one to one relationships?

B) Should I use Hibernate's lazy property fetching? Even the manual says it's "mostly a marketing feature"?

C) Is there some other way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of JPQL `NEW` operator.
You can create some DTO object and initialize it in the JPQL query:

```
public class PersonDTO {

   private String firstName;
   private String surname;

   public PersonDTO(String firstName, String surname) {
      this.firstName = firstName;
      this.surname = surname;
   }

   // getters setters

}

Select NEW PersonDTO(p.firstName, p.surname) From Person p;
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the `ORM` at its best I would go for solution one to respect the `OOP` paradigm and try to encapsulate things. I am guessing that if you mainly need only two properties then it makes sense to have a Class dedicated for the use of those two and associate it with some other classes.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility you could consider is simply defining two different mappings for the same table. E.g. `PersonOverview` would only map a couple of properties, and would mostly be used to fetch large collections of persons, whereas `PersonDetails` would map all available person properties, but would only ever be used if one particular person needs to be fetched for displaying/editing.